# Ruby regex extract words between {{word|word|word} {word|word|word}}

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I get the individual words contained only within `{}` out of the text

```
an example of the text {Creating|Making|Producing} blah blah blah
```

or

```
another example of the text {{In order to|As a way to|So that you can|To be able to} {connect|link|join}} blah blah blah
```

I have got this far with my limited regex knowledge

```
text.scan(/{([^}]*)}/)[0][0].split('|')
```

but this selects the text `{In order to|As a way to|So that you can|To be able to` and splits it like so `{In order to`

How can I select the text only within the `{}`?

Expected output

```
["In order to", "As a way to", "So that you can", "To be able to"]
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I just want the text and no {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
text.scan(/{([^{}]*)}/)[0][0].split('|')
```